# Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}$ not uniformly continuous on $(3,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

Intro: I would to show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(3,\infty)$. I would like to use the theorem that states: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a set $S$ and $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $S$, then $f(s_n)$ is a Cauchy Sequence.

My work so far$\rightarrow$ Proof: To get a contradiction, assume $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}$ is uniformly continuous. **The sequence $(s_n)$ defined by $s_n=e^{-x}+3$ lies in $(3,\infty)$** and converges to $3$, so $s_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence. By the assumption and the theorem above, $$f(s_n)=\frac{1}{(e^{-x}+3)-3}=e^{x}$$is a Cauchy Sequence. This is a contradiction because the sequence $(e^{x})$ diverges to $+\infty$, so it cannot be a Cauchy sequence; therefore, $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $(3, \infty)$. $\square$

I am concerned that my chosen $s_n$ will not work since its domain is $(-\infty,\infty)$. Is it true that $s_n$ lies in $(3,\infty)$? That is, am I okay to state the **bolded** part of my proof?  Clearly $(3,\infty)$ lies in $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Any help with this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It should be $s_n = e^{-n} + 3$, elsewise you are fine, both the **bolded** part, and the proof itself. Have you seen a proof of the theorem you are using to prove this example?  Also, the fact that $s_n \to 3$ is insignificant, since $3$ does not belong to $(3 , \infty)$, and it's enough that $s_n$ be Cauchy, so we need not observe where it converges.

Comment: Yes $s_n$ does lie in $(3, \infty)$. Range of $e^{-x}$ is $(0,\infty)$, so the range of $e^{-x}+3$ is $(3,\infty)$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the help. Yes, I have seen the proof of the theorem I am using.